# How can I change the layout of my page so that it doesn't block everything on one page?

Tags: formatting, luatex, document-classes

I've been writing my CV in LaTeX and used a template. The issue is that where I've put all my entries into this specific section it's grouped all of my entries together in one block and put them on the next page leaving half a page blank.

The relevant code that came with the template is below, I am wondering how I can change it so that it will allow the entries to spill across multiple pages instead of putting it all together on the next page with the requisite space?

Thanks.

```
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll}
}{%
  \end{tabular*}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.4cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Implementing the above code:

```
\section{Experience}
\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{This text is the wrong colour}
{Text}
{Text}
{\emph{Bold text} \\
Text.}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{This text is the wrong colour}
{Text}
{Text}
{\emph{Bold text} \\
Text.}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{This text is the wrong colour}
{Text}
{Text}
{\emph{Bold text} \\
Text.}
%------------------------------------------------
\entry
{This text is the wrong colour}
{Text}
{Text}
{\emph{Bold text} \\
Text.}
%------------------------------------------------
\end{entrylist}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  You will find that the help you receive will be better and quicker if you can distill your question down to a [minimum working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).  Additionally, once you create the MWE, put all of the code here in this question so it is still available when someone reads this much later.

Comment: I have edited my question now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With only code fragments to go by, I can't be entirely confident that this will work. You could use a `longtable` environment instead of a `tabular*` environment, along the following lines:

```
\usepackage{longtable}
\newenvironment{entrylist}{%
  \setlength\LTleft{0pt}
  \setlength\LTright{0pt}
  \begin{longtable}{@{}l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}l@{}} % this tells 'longtable' to take up 
                                                    % the full width of the textblock
  }{%
  \end{longtable}
}
\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\headingfont\color{headercolor}}
\newcommand{\entry}[4]{%
  #1&\parbox[t]{11.4cm}{%
    \textbf{#2}%
    \hfill%
    {\footnotesize\addfontfeature{Color=lightgray} #3}\\%
    #4\vspace{\parsep}%
  }\\}
```

Comment: That's brilliant, it's all perfectly formatted now. Thanks a lot. :D

Comment: @Stormie - I'm delighted that my guess was on target!

Comment: I do have one more question now though, after applying the fix it's changed the text colour for the left column, any idea on how I can change the colour back?

Comment: @Stormie - Could you augment your posting to show the use of the `\entry` macro in action? I see it takes four arguments, but I have no idea what the arguments are: Text, numbers, macros?

Comment: Updated, though I had to remov the actual text. I hope this helps!

Comment: @Stormie - which document class do you use, and how is `\headingfont` defined?

Comment: My document class: documentclass[]{friggeri-cv}

With the friggeri-cv being the pastebin link. :)

Comment: @Stormie - I've had a chance now to work with the document class you're using. I had to comment out the font-related commands since my system doesn't have the fonts in question. I'm afraid I can see no difference in the colors of the material in the first column when using (a) the `tabular*` environment provided in your posting (and the document class) and (b) the proposed solution of using `longtable`. I must be missing something, but I can't tell what it may be.

Comment: Hmmm, I suppose I'll have to leave it as black then.

Thanks a lot for your help anyway. :)